# Can someone look at the solution to this question and explain it more clearly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

the following is the solution.
[image]

Here is my question.. what is the "positive quantity" and how did $x + \frac{36}{x} \ge 13$ become $x^2 - 13x + 36 \ge 0$?

Thank you!

Comment: Corrected a typo in your question.

Comment: The "positive quantity" is $x$

Answer (score 0):

The "positive quantity" is $x$, since we are considering the case $x > 0$.  Multiplying the original inequality by this quantity (i.e., by $x$), we get
$$
x^2 + 36 \geq 13 x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The "positive quantity" referenced in the solution is $x$. The author places this emphasis on $x$ being positive because the techniques that follow are only valid when $x$ is a positive real number.

Given that $x>0$, we have

$$
x + \frac{36}{x} \geq 13 \iff x^2 + 36 \geq 13x \iff x^2 - 13x + 36 \geq 0
$$
as desired.

Comment: so you can't multiply the equation by x if x is negative?

Comment: @KeKe it's inequality, not equation. If $5 > 3$, the you claim $-5 > -3$?